# Erro de lógica?

Tags: prolog

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
mãe(ana, eva).
mãe(eva, noé).
mãe(bia, raí).
mãe(bia, clô).
mãe(bia, ary).
mãe(lia, gal).
pai(ivo, eva).
pai(raí, noé).
pai(gil, raí).
pai(gil, clô).
pai(gil, ary).
pai(ary, gal).
avô(X, Y) :- pai(X, Z), pai(Z, Y); pai(X, Z), mãe(Z, Y).
```

Ao fazer a consulta:

```
avô(X, Y).
```

O SWI-Prolog me retorna:

```
X = gil,
Y = noé ;
X = gil,
Y = gal ;
X = ivo,
Y = noé ;
false.
```

Eu pensava que ele deveria retornar 'true', mas não entendi se eu cometi um erro de lógica pois não consigo identificá-lo, gostaria de saber a razão de retornar 'false' (sou bem iniciante). Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nao ha erro nenhum no seu codigo. O prolog esta retornando todos os pares `(X,Y)` que satisfazem a query `avo(X,Y)`.

Ele iria retornar `true` se voce fizesse uma pergunta em que ambas as "variaveis" X e Y "tem algum valor":

```
avo(gil, noe)
```

por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer.

Comment: +1 só complementando: ele retorna `false` porque você pediu "mais resultados" (comando `;`) depois que todos os resultados possíveis já tinham sido explorados. Ou seja, o `false` quer dizer "tem mais resultados? não."

Answer (score -4):

Nao ha erro nenhum no seu codigo. O prolog esta retornando todos os pares (X,Y) que satisfazem a query avo(X,Y).